# Как поменять цвет текста внутри чарта D3 js?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

блок с текстом выглядит так

```
g.append("text")
 .attr  ("class", "percent-score")
 .attr  ("dy", ".35em")
 .attr  ("text-anchor", "middle")
 .text  (innerText);
```

стили

```
.percent-score {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

изменяются все параметры кроме цвета.

[весь код](https://codepen.io/Divatoz/pen/WNodKXB?editors=0110)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы изменить цвет текста вместо color нужно использовать fill

```
.percent-score {
  fill: red;
}
```